# Entity Framework Core multiple relations to a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, .net-6.0, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework Core 7.0.2 in ASP.NET Core Web API written in C#.

I have multiple tables and they are all connected with one-to-many relation.

See the following tree how all tables are connected.

[image: Tree]

I just added 2 extra tables which are connected to Trades.

This is how my modal looks like:

```
public class Trade
{
    [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string TradingJournalId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Improvement> Improvements { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Before I added the other 2 tables called Improvements and Tags my query for collecting the user with the relation is the following:

```
var user = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.TradingJournal)
    .ThenInclude(t => t.Trades)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.Attachments)
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
```

If I try the following it will result in a error because in will look into the Attachment table.

```
var user = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.TradingJournal)
    .ThenInclude(t => t.Trades)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.Attachments)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.Tags)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.Improvements)
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
```

This is my preferable output.

```
{
    "Id": "114af6db-0124-4573-9ab9-d676f8c05a48",
    "TradingJournal": [
        {
            "Id": "fa0eef8c-16fd-416e-97ec-df6f43c448f2",
            "UserId": "114af6db-0124-4573-9ab9-d676f8c05a48",
            "Trades": [
                {
                    "Id": "4e7ebfd4-54dc-48c7-9e23-01312295f431",
                    "TradingJournalId": "fa0eef8c-16fd-416e-97ec-df6f43c448f2",
                    "Attachments": [
                        {
                            "Id": "362be948-8bc3-4172-ad19-9625bb5aebf4",
                            "TradeId": "4e7ebfd4-54dc-48c7-9e23-01312295f431",
                        }
                    ],
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Id": "362be948-8bc3-4172-ad19-96252b54ebf2",
                            "TradeId": "4e7ebfd4-54dc-48c7-9e23-01312295f431",
                        }
                    ],
                    "Improvements": [
                        {
                            "Id": "362be948-8bc3-4172-ad19-9625bb5ae3f8",
                            "TradeId": "4e7ebfd4-54dc-48c7-9e23-01312295f431",
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

At the moment the Tags and Improvements are both null.

I got no clue how I need to solve this by adding a reference to the other 2 tables. I did some research how to do it but my case is much more complicated due the multiple relations hence the help I need.

Edit:

Here are all the entities modals.

```
public class User
{
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TradingJournal> TradingJournal { get; set; }
}

public class TradingJournal
{
    [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
}

public class Trade
{
    [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string TradingJournalId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Improvement> Improvements { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string TradeId { get; set; }
}

public class Improvement
{
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string TradeId { get; set; }
}

public class Tags
{
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required][StringLength(50)][Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")] public string TradeId { get; set; }
}
```

I have removed all the irrelevant properties in the modals which aren't needed for the reference tables so that this code is much more readable.

Comment: _"it will result in a error"_ and concrete error text?

Comment: Also please add code for all related entities.

Comment: @GuruStron

THe following error:

`'ICollection «Attachment>' does not contain a definition for 'Improvements' and no accessible extension method
'Improvements' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Attachment>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference.)`

Comment: @GuruStron have added the related entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThenInclude` allows to include properties of "previous" entity, so in this case it would be `Attachments` which have not `Tags` or `Improvements`. AFAIK EF Core still does not allow "walk backs" so try the following:

```cs
var user = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.TradingJournal)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Trades)
            .ThenInclude(f => f.Attachments)
    .Include(u => u.TradingJournal)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Trades)
            .ThenInclude(f => f.Tags)
    .Include(u => u.TradingJournal)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Trades)
            .ThenInclude(f => f.Improvements)
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
```

Check out the [Including multiple levels section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels) of eager loading docs.

Comment: I tried your code and but I got a really strange error. I also look into the article.

Error:

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at lambda_method40(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor

Comment: @GuruSton see the following stacktrace image 
https://pasteboard.co/AWkVqffbO0ks.jpg

Comment: @ChahinDev check that string constraints are satisfied - i.e. database matches the model and you don't have longer strings, or you are not passing longer search id. Also seems that your ids are actually `Guid`s - why not just use this type?

Comment: It worked now. I changed every string to Guid for better code and I had a stupid mistake on Tag where I had this property as int but should be a string

 [Required][Column(TypeName = "varchar(40)")] public int Name { get; set; }
Hence why the System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format error.

Thank you very much @GuruStron